# Android Layout Background Dynamically

Tags: android, background

I have a relative layout:

```
RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

How can I set a background to the layout (dynamically not in xml) and have it stretch to fill the entire screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
```

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) for methods you need.